# rammap issues - does not show up anything (win10 pro build 17120)

Tags: memory, windows-10-preview, memory-management

I'm having some issues with the windows [rammap tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/rammap). It used to work fine but by going to recent builds 17115/17120 it stopped working - when i start it up it does not show up anything. Refreshing it causes it to crash. I tried re-installing it but no luck. Searching through the web also does not show up anything useful, besides some stale forums.
I'm wondering if anyone has faced similar issues or can point me to ways to resolve this. I'm on win10 pro build 17120 rs4 180309-1616.

**Edit** - as pointed out by @Epoxy in the comments, here are the event error logs.

```
1. Application Error event -----

* 1.1 General *

Faulting application name: RAMMap64.exe, version: 1.50.0.0, time stamp: 0x56a9c074
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.17120.1, time stamp: 0xe5136909
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000f50cb
Faulting process id: 0x1954
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3c1083d80f478
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\RAMMap\RAMMap64.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 8002f6e8-ca88-49d2-a4d7-07aeda4dceed
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:  

* 1.2 Details * 

- System 
- Provider 
  [ Name]  Application Error 
- EventID 1000 
  [ Qualifiers]  0 
Level 2 
Task 100 
Keywords 0x80000000000000 
- TimeCreated 
  [ SystemTime]  2018-03-21T11:32:45.093706100Z 
EventRecordID 1843 
Channel Application 
Computer David-Desktop 
Security 
- EventData 
   RAMMap64.exe 
   1.50.0.0 
   56a9c074 
   ntdll.dll 
   10.0.17120.1 
   e5136909 
   c0000374 
   00000000000f50cb 
   1954 
   01d3c1083d80f478 
   C:\Program Files\RAMMap\RAMMap64.exe 
   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll 
   8002f6e8-ca88-49d2-a4d7-07aeda4dceed

2. Windows Error Reporting event -----

* 2.1 General * 

Fault bucket 1880635345925225307, type 4
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
  P1: RAMMap64.exe
P2: 1.50.0.0
P3: 56a9c074
P4: StackHash_cbfa
P5: 10.0.17120.1
P6: e5136909
P7: c0000374
P8: PCH_20_FROM_ntdll+0x000000000009ABC4
P9: 
  P10: 

  Attached files:
  \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER123B.tmp.mdmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER127A.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER128B.tmp.xml
WPR_initiated_DiagTrackMiniLogger_One Trace User Logger_20180319 Event Collector_0_inject.etl
\\?\C:\Users\David_Jankoski\AppData\Local\Temp\WER1309.tmp.etl
WPR_initiated_DiagTrackMiniLogger_WPR System Collector_inject.etl
\\?\C:\Users\David_Jankoski\AppData\Local\Temp\WER130A.tmp.etl
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER1308.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER1318.tmp.txt

These files may be available here:
  C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_RAMMap64.exe_1c39d666fb7c699d861d89961ee7a4e57d783d7d_92e8a64a_236b1911

Analysis symbol: 
  Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 8002f6e8-ca88-49d2-a4d7-07aeda4dceed
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed bucket: 21e4a91eb4cb40a98a195be211eabb5b
Cab Guid: 0

* 2.2 Details *

+ System 

- Provider 

[ Name]  Windows Error Reporting 

- EventID 1001 

[ Qualifiers]  0 

Level 4 

Task 0 

Keywords 0x80000000000000 

- TimeCreated 

[ SystemTime]  2018-03-21T11:32:46.920970900Z 

EventRecordID 1844 

Channel Application 

Computer David-Desktop 

Security 


- EventData 

1880635345925225307 
4 
APPCRASH 
Not available 
0 
RAMMap64.exe 
1.50.0.0 
56a9c074 
StackHash_cbfa 
10.0.17120.1 
e5136909 
c0000374 
PCH_20_FROM_ntdll+0x000000000009ABC4 


\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER123B.tmp.mdmp \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER127A.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER128B.tmp.xml WPR_initiated_DiagTrackMiniLogger_One Trace User Logger_20180319 Event Collector_0_inject.etl \\?\C:\Users\David_Jankoski\AppData\Local\Temp\WER1309.tmp.etl WPR_initiated_DiagTrackMiniLogger_WPR System Collector_inject.etl \\?\C:\Users\David_Jankoski\AppData\Local\Temp\WER130A.tmp.etl \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER1308.tmp.csv \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER1318.tmp.txt 
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_RAMMap64.exe_1c39d666fb7c699d861d89961ee7a4e57d783d7d_92e8a64a_236b1911 

0 
8002f6e8-ca88-49d2-a4d7-07aeda4dceed 
268435456 
21e4a91eb4cb40a98a195be211eabb5b 
0
```

Comment: Are you able to look into the Windows event log? Simply search for event viewer. Then run the app. Go to Windows Logs > Application and see if you find any errors. Posting these will be able to help the others to determine the issue.

Comment: thanks for the hint - indeed launching the rammap tools and refreshing it causes 2 events in the event viewer. I included the information from both of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RAMMap uses internal API to query the memory data. Such API change in new Windows 10 versions. And it looks like Microsoft made some changes in the last RS4 preview Builds that cause the tool to fail.

So go back to the Windows 10 v1709 or wait until next month when Windows 10 v1803 gets official released. I think Mark will update all tools to make them compatible.

Comment: great, thanks. i was just worried that something "bigger" is going on since i upgraded to these builds - i noticed huge RAM usage at start up (15GB, half of my avail ram), with no other programmes started up. trying to inspect what's going on with the rammap lead to this.

Comment: open a new question about the memory usage and post Taskmgr->Perf->Memory pictures. Also open cmd.exe as admin, run **wpr.exe -start ReferenceSet -filemode && timeout 5 && wpr.exe -stop C:\HighMemoryUsage.etl**. this captures the memory usage. Post a onedrive share link to the compressed ETL (this reduces upload and download size) in the new question.

Comment: that's great, didn't know this - thanks. will post a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

[Rammap 1.52](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap) released June 28, 2019 works fine on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Version 1903.

Answer (score 0):

Hitting the "Empty - Standby List" still works in RamMap. To check open Resource Monitor (use search to find on your PC) and click on the Memory tab. At the bottom the memory use will show. Checking the before and after you will see that RamMap will reset the standby memory back to zero. The new Windows update has caused RamMap to no longer display the memory.